# Javascript build object with properties

Tags: javascript

i have this code:

```
HTTP.get(
  `url`,
  { "params": {"id": id},
    "headers": {"h1": getH1(), "h2": getH2()}
  }
```

what i want is to construct the headers not in seperate functions but in one function for all the headers. Something like this:

```
HTTP.get(
  `url`,
  { "params": {"id": id},
     createHeaders(); //or "headers": {createHeaders()};
  }
```

so in my createHeaders() i can choose which of h1,h2...hn i add.

The createHeaders should look somethig like this (pseudocode):

```
function createHeaders(){
    var headers;
    if(cond1)
        headers.addHeader1();
    if(cond2)
        headers.addHeader2();
    if(cond3)
        ...

    return headers;
}
```

Can this be done in JavaScript?

Pls take a look at the createHeaders function. What i am looking for is, how to construct the headers object and what is to return to the HTT.get().

Comment: *Can this be done in JavaScript?* Yes. You can look into `Object.assign`

Comment: You could just do `"headers": createHeaders()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var _headers = getHeaders(anyArguments);
HTTP.get(
  `url`,
  { 
    "params": {"id": id},
    "headers": _headers 
  }
//
function getHeaders(){
   var _headers;
   if(cond1){
     _headers.h1="";
   }
   return _headers;
}
```

Comment: going to try this, but did you accidentaly swap _headers with getHeaders() ?

Comment: I did not understand "but did you accidentaly swap _headers with getHeaders() ? "

Furthermore, I forgot to return '_headers' in getHeaders. You may skip "var _headers = getHeaders(anyArguments);" and directly use getHeaders function  "headers":getHeaders(anyArguments)

Comment: it is fixed now

Comment: BTW does underscore have a special function or is this just a naming convention for variables?

Comment: @Gobliins It is just naming convention

Answer (score 1):

You can look into following

#### [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

`Object.assign` is used to merge objects or copy objects into one target object. Its very handy but its a new feature and is not supported by all browsers. Please check [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility) before using.

```js
function getHeaders() {
  var header = {
    header: null
  }
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 ) % 2
  header.header = random === 0 ? "Random is odd" : "Random is even";
  return header
}


function makeAPICall() {
  var params = {
    url: '/test/foo123'
  }
  Object.assign(params, getHeaders());
  console.log(params);
}
makeAPICall();
```

#### Pass Reference

Objects in JS are passed by reference. You can also pass object's reference and update it.

```js
function setHeaders(obj) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) % 2
  if(random)
    obj.header = "Random is odd"
  else
    obj.header = "random is even"
}


function makeAPICall() {
  var params = {
    url: '/test/foo123'
  }
  setHeaders(params);
  console.log(params);
}
makeAPICall();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your can do this

```
   HTTP.get(
      `url`,
      { 
        "params": {"id": id},
        "headers": createHeader(condition)
      }

    function createHeader(condition) {
      switch(condition) {
         case one:
            return {"h1": getH1(), "h2": getH2()}
         case two:
            return {"h3": getH1(), "h4": getH2()}
      }
    }
```

Comment: what i am missing here is how to conditionaly add the headers

Comment: changed something check now

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is what you wanna accomplish :

```js
getH1 = () => 'hello';
getH2 = () => 'world';

function createHeaders(cond){
    var headers = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      switch (arguments[i]) {
        case 1:
        headers.h1 = getH1();
        break;
        case 2:
        headers.h2 = getH2();
        break;
      }
    }
    return headers;
}
console.log('"headers": ', createHeaders(1, 2));
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: in case i want both headers i would just do `headers += ...` and put the brackets on top and bottom of the switch case statement, right?

Comment: @Gobliins in this case.. yes

Comment: Ok, the problem at this solution is, we don't actually get objects returned, we only get a string, so the HTTP.get() is not working as intended.

Comment: @Gobliins check the updated answer. now it should work perfectly fine as you expected. :)

Comment: I gave plus one for working solution, it's actually now the same as the one from ZAiD Chauhan